# Why toggling textarea to readonly property with javascript is affected by alert prompt?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a couple of textareas on a page that load as readonly. I want user to toggle this property by double clicking them.

When I add listener events in js file for some reason they work when alert line is present in them and don't work without it. I cannot figure out the reason.
Why this happens and how can i make this toggle to work without the alerts.

This code works, but apparently is not what i want:

```js
var t_areas = document.querySelectorAll("textarea");

for(var i = 0; i < t_areas.length; i++){
 t_areas[i].addEventListener("dblclick", function(){
  if (this.readOnly == true){
   this.readOnly = false;
   alert("12")
  }
  else {
   this.readOnly = true;
   alert("22")
  }
 });
```

```html
<textarea class="bg-secondary text-white medium border-0 col-md-10" id="aosr_3" aria-describedby="aosrNumber" rows = "2" readonly="true">Readonly text</textarea>
```

This one doesn't work, although I only removed alert prompts.

```js
var t_areas = document.querySelectorAll("textarea");

for(var i = 0; i < t_areas.length; i++){
 t_areas[i].addEventListener("dblclick", function(){
  if (this.readOnly == true){
   this.readOnly = false;
   alert("12")
  }
  else {
   this.readOnly = true;
   alert("22")
  }
 });
```

```html
<textarea class="bg-secondary text-white medium border-0 col-md-10" id="aosr_3" aria-describedby="aosrNumber" rows = "2" readonly="true">Readonly text</textarea>
```

Comment: When I 'Run code snippet' on your code I get an error - could you please fix it? Or make a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

use `mousedown` event instead of `click`

```
$("div").mousedown(function(){
  $(this).after("Mouse btn is pressed down.");
});
```

This could be due to conflict in events that are fired all at the same time. Put delay to check that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it is working.

```
<textarea class="bg-secondary text-white medium border-0 col-md-10" id="aosr_3" aria-describedby="aosrNumber" rows = "2" readonly="true">Readonly text</textarea>

var t_areas = document.querySelectorAll("textarea");
    //alert("hello")
    for(var i = 0; i < t_areas.length; i++)
    {

        t_areas[i].addEventListener("dblclick", function(){

            if (this.hasAttribute("readonly")){

                this.removeAttribute("readonly");

            }
            else {

                this.setAttribute("readonly","true");

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your code snippet also does not work in my browser (Chrome), but when I add allert into each if block it starts working

Comment: In chrome it is working but the problem is after double clicking inside textarea you have to make click on outside textarea then this will work. Thats why when you click on alert box you are clicking ok button thats why it is working. But where as in firefox it is working well.Another one is the blinking caret cursor is also in textarea only.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing curly brace at the end of your for loop block. The browser was outputting the error "unexpected end of input", meaning, it expected some sort of closing.

Edit: the text itself must be double clicked, or the event doesn't seem to fire.

Edit Edit: It seems to work selectively, may I suggest a simpler solution? Perhaps add an "edit" button.

```
<textarea class="bg-secondary text-white medium border-0 col-md-10" id="aosr_3" aria-describedby="aosrNumber" rows = "2" readonly="true">Readonly text</textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
var t_areas = document.querySelectorAll("textarea");

for(var i = 0; i < t_areas.length; i++){
    t_areas[i].addEventListener("dblclick", function(){
        if (this.readOnly == true){
            this.readOnly = false;
        }
        else {
            this.readOnly = true;
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Although I forgot this curly brace while asking question, I had it in my code. Unfortunately, this code snippet also does not work in my browser (Chrome), but when I add allert into each if block it starts working

Comment: That's really strange, I was running it and it seemed to work. I guess it might be because I was using a fiddle, but it worked in chrome. Edit: You have to double click the text itself, or the event doesn't seem to fire. Edit Edit: It seems to work selectively, may I suggest a simpler solution? Perhaps add an "edit" button.